# How to use acceptCall function having Context?

Tags: android, android-studio, receiver

I want to use this function to accept an incoming call, but how do I use the function and how I can put parameter?
I want to edit this function with my class.

Here is my function :

```
public static void acceptCall(Context context) 
{
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, 
        new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

this is my class :

```
package com.bitgriff.androidcalls;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Helper class to detect incoming and outgoing calls.
 * @author Moskvichev Andrey V.
 *
 */
public class CallHelper {

    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls. 
     */
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                //------------------------
                //Not work
                //acceptCall();

                //---------------------------------
                Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                        "Incoming: "+incomingNumber, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void acceptCall(Context context){
        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }

/*
    private void rejectCall(Context context)
    {
        Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON); buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }
    */
    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                    "Outgoing: "+number, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on which class from you are calling this method.
if you are in Activity then pass `this` as parameter.
if in fragment then pass `getContext();`
if you are in Thread inside Activity then pass `ActivityName.this` as parameter.

Comment: From within the same class  ,How I will call a function with put parameter ?

Comment: is that class an Activity??

Comment: in your code you have passed Context "ctx". where from that ctx came??

Comment: and your Class `CallHelper` doesn't extend Activity or Fragment, so you have to create a Constructor with Context. wait i am adding new post with code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code your class CallHelper doesn't extend Activity or Fragment, so create a constructor in that class. 
Example:

```
class CallHelper{
    private Context context;
    public CallHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

}
```

now pass context in your method.

and inside your activity where you have called this class as

```
CallHelper callHelper = new CallHelpe();
```

change this to

```
CallHelper callHelper = new CallHelper(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, does not work,The function used to open incoming calls ,It has developed within this the class
Which is part of the knowledge of the call number Program  ,    How do they merged together to open the call

Comment: Where you want to call that method??? And this method is static method so that method will be also static method who will call this method

Comment: inside these  function  onCallStateChanged  uderline  :                              case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:                                                         Is not a problem , even if we have to modify is not the case static

Comment: then make your `acceptCall(Context context)` method `non-static`

Comment: Without any a parameter ,Does not work without a parameter

Comment: It does not accept the Add function :   public CallHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }                                                                                                                  then it  Give me mis   in  parameter  On the inside of the functionacceptCall(Context context)

Comment: I can not post  public CallHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }                             or acceptCall(Context context)

Comment: When you add the function : public CallHelper(Context context){
  this.context = context;
 }                                                                                                            I find mis with text explains                                                CallHelper(Context )is already defined in 'com.bitgriff.androidcall.CallHelper